# Google Colab Pro not allocating more than 1 GB of GPU memory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I recently upgraded to colab pro. I am trying to use GPU resources from colab pro to train my Mask RCNN model. I was allocated around 15 GB of memory when I tried to run the model right after I signed up for Pro. However, for some reason, I was allocated just 1 GB of memory from the next morning. Since then, I haven't been allocated more than 1 GB. I was wondering if I am missing something or I perturbed the VM inherent packages. I understand that the allocation varies from day to day, but it's been like this for almost 3 days now.  Following attempts have already made to improve, but none seems to work.

- I have made sure that GPU and "High-RAM" option is selected.
- I have tried restarting runtimes several times
- I have tried running other scripts (just to make sure that problem was not with mask rcnn script)

I would appreciate any suggestions on this issue.

[GPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVfE1.jpg)[image: GPU selection]

Answer (score 0):

The high memory setting in the screen controls the system RAM rather than GPU memory.

The command `!nvidia-smi` will show GPU memory. For example:

[image]

The highlighted output shows the GPU memory utilization: 0 of 16 GB.

Comment: I had also checked for GPU by using command !watch nvidia-smi. The info shows just 835 MB out of 16 GB (Please see the GPU info link in the original post for the screenshot of the info; it's kind of hidden due to another image).

Comment: 835 MB of 16 GB means that you have used 835 MB, leaving 15 GB remaining. I suspect that you are encountering a system memory exceeded error rather than a GPU memory exceeded error.

Comment: I have never encountered the exceeding error. My question is why am I not able to utilize all of the 15 GB memory or at least greater than 1 GB memory. I am stuck with 873 MiB of GPU memory. With colab pro, ain't I suppose to get more allocation?

Comment: Memory usage is a function of the code in your notebook. If it only needs 835 MB, that's all that will be used. Do you have a reason to expect your work to use more memory?

Comment: I am using Mask RCNN model and my dataset is huge. This model uses tensorflow as the backend. I definitely think that it's going to use more memory. What would be my move now?

Comment: I'd recommend using the [TensorFlow profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/tensorboard_profiling_keras) in order to understand how your workflow is interacting with hardware like the GPU. Your data may be large, but the way your computation is structured may not involve all of the data being resident in GPU memory. Stepping back a bit, why is using so little memory a problem? Is the real problem poor performance of model training? Low accuracy? Something else?