# Unable to ultilize full GPU allocation in Colab

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, face-recognition

I am trying to run a Deep Learning based Face Recognition Model. But when I run it on Google Colab, it uses only 1.12 GB of GPU out of 42 GB. I have enabled and checked all the configuration of colab and in the code using Pytorch wrapper.

Please help how can I use full resource in Colab.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your issue was discussed here on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912746/google-colab-pro-not-allocating-more-than-1-gb-of-gpu-memory)
"

> The high memory setting in the screen controls the system RAM
> rather than GPU memory. The command !nvidia-smi will show GPU memory.
> For example:
> [image]

.. and also was answered here in Google Colab docs
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/pro.ipynb